# How to Verify If two hostnames or i.p address points to same machine in c++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ip-address, hostname

I have some machines and hostnames are defined for them. I want to write a c++ program that checks if both the hostnames points to different machine and execute some steps. If both of them points to same machine program should be terminated. strcmp cant be used to compare as a machine can have multiple hostnames.

Comment: Resolve the hostnames then compare the ips?

Comment: Virtual Machines greatly complicate this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to understand what "machine" stands for.
A host can have multiple IP addresses (e.g. two network cards/NICs).

If you are willing to test only for "the same IP" - then you can use the
`gethostbyname()` call to resolve different names to the actual IP.

Even this is not fire-proof, as it relies on LOCAL resources (DNS) to do
the translation, and if it is not set up correctly can lead to different results.

One way to know for sure is to set up an agent on the remote machine (or use something like telnet or ping) that actually try to access the name/address and see whether they go to the same destination.

Comment: I am not bothered about network IPs. Does each machine have its own unique ip address?

Comment: @rsev4292340: Usually yes, at least locally. However, 192.168.1.1 is not globally unique; there are millions of machines with that address.